# Calculating Normals for Surface in Open GL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am trying to add shading/lighting to my terrain generator. But for some reason my output still looks blocky even after I calculate surface normals.

```
set<pair<int,int> >::const_iterator it;

for ( it = mRandomPoints.begin(); it != mRandomPoints.end(); ++it )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < GetXSize(); ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < GetZSize(); ++j )
        {
            float pd = sqrt(pow((*it).first - i,2) + pow((*it).second - j,2))*2 / mCircleSize;
            if(fabs(pd) <= 1.0)
            {
                mMap[i][j][2] += mCircleHeight/2 + cos(pd*3.14)*mCircleHeight/2; ;
            }

        }
    }
}

/*
    The three points being considered to compute normals are 
    (i,j)
    (i+1,j)
    (i, j+1)
*/

for ( int i = 0; i < GetXSize() -1 ; ++i )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < GetZSize() - 1; ++j )
    {
        float b[] = {mMap[i+1][j][0]-mMap[i][j][0], mMap[i+1][j][1]-mMap[i][j][1], mMap[i+1][j][2]-mMap[i][j][2] };
        float c[] = {mMap[i][j+1][0]-mMap[i][j][0], mMap[i][j+1][1]-mMap[i][j][1], mMap[i][j+1][2]-mMap[i][j][2] };
        float a[] = {b[1]*c[2] - b[2]*c[1], b[2]*c[0]-b[0]*c[2], b[0]*c[1]-b[1]*c[0]};

        float Vnorm = sqrt(pow(a[0],2) + pow(a[1],2) + pow(a[2],2));

        mNormalMap[i][j][0] = a[0]/Vnorm;
        mNormalMap[i][j][1] = a[1]/Vnorm;
        mNormalMap[i][j][2] = a[2]/Vnorm;

    }
}
```

Then when drawing this I use the following

```
float*** normal = map->GetNormalMap();

for (int i = 0 ; i < map->GetXSize() - 1; ++i)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int j = 0; j < map->GetZSize() - 1; ++j)
    {

        glNormal3fv(normal[i][j]);


        float color = 1 - (terrain[i][j][2]/height);
        glColor3f(color,color, color);
        glVertex3f(terrain[i][j][0], terrain[i][j][2], terrain[i][j][1]);
        glVertex3f(terrain[i+1][j][0], terrain[i+1][j][2], terrain[i+1][j][1]);
        glVertex3f(terrain[i][j+1][0], terrain[i][j+1][2], terrain[i][j+1][1]);
        glVertex3f(terrain[i+1][j+1][0], terrain[i+1][j+1][2], terrain[i+1][j+1][1]);
    }

    glEnd();
}
```

EDIT: Initialization Code

```
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT); // glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
```

Am I calculating the Normals Properly?

Comment: Sidenote: you're using as inefficient code as possible. Why not `a[0] * a[0]` instead of `pow(a[0], 2)`? Why calculate the square root and then use slooooow floating-point division instead of just using the [fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)?

Comment: New to graphics programming here, I am not really looking to make it super efficient, but +1 for mentioning fast inverse square root.

Comment: I just added that I see no difference

Comment: @BЈовић And what does `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` have to do with this (or did you just mean `GL_SMOOTH`?)? @OP don't use that `glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)` in there, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, `rsqrt` isn't the non-plus-ultra and I wouldn't blame anybody for not using it, but Ok, `pow(a, 2)` is indeed ridiculous.

Comment: @ChristianRau doh right. I meant glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what Bovinedragon suggested, namely `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);`, you should probably use per-vertex normals. This means that each `glVertex3f` would be preceded by a `glNormal3fv` call, which would define the average normal of all adjacent faces. To obtain it, you can simply add up these neighbouring normal vectors and normalize the result.

[image]

Reference this question: [Techniques to smooth face edges in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954039/techniques-to-smooth-face-edges-in-opengl)

Answer (score 2):

Have you set glShadeModel to GL_SMOOTH?

See: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glShadeModel.html

This settings also effects vertex colors in addition to lighting.  You seem to say it was blocky even before lighting which makes me think this is the issue.

Comment: I think num3ric has the correct answer.  One other thing I notice is that you are not calculating vertex normals completely correct.  Usually to calculate the normal of a vertex you average the normals of each of the faces that touch that vertex.  It looks like you are just picking one of the faces vertex and using its normal without considering the other ones.